# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function while creating a subview using backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am creating a subView which is rendered from the mainview - FindRideView.

```
renderRide: function (item) {
        var RideView = new RideView({model: item}); // here
    this.$el.append(RideView.render().el);
    }
```

However when i render the view,
 i get a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function //here`

My app structure is

```
 var RideView = Backbone.View.extend({});
 var FindRideView = Backbone.View.extend({
    renderRide:
    });
```

I checked with the RideView for any errors. But its working completely fine when not called from the FindRideView. I guess there might be some scope issue, but i am not sure about it.
Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Your code seems fine, can you try to recreate your problem in a JSFiddle?

Comment: Try naming your instance something other than `RideView` since that is the exact same as your constructor.

Comment: nialed it!! haha!
renaming it to something else did the trick :)
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try defining "RideView" outside of the function. See this for a scoping example:

http://jsfiddle.net/54DRC/3/

```
var mynum;
mynum = 1;
function DontSetMyNum() {
    var mynum;
    mynum = 2;
}
function SetMyNum() {
    mynum = 3;
}
$(function() {
    $("body").append("<p>Initial = " + mynum + "</p>");
    DontSetMyNum();
    $("body").append("<p>After DontSetMyNum call = " + mynum + "</p>");
    SetMyNum();
    $("body").append("<p>After SetMyNum call = " + mynum + "</p>");
});
```